# Will using an array of arrays impact on performance

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make up my mind between allowing one of my functions accept either an array of arrays or just an a standard array.

The array with arrays will allow me to verify each array key, but it is not necessary if I am able to see an improved performance from using a standard array.

Is there any performance difference between the two (performance wise)?

e.g.

**arrays of arrays**

```
$arr2 = array(
   array('isbn' => '1846031249'),
   array('isbn' => '0340912081'),
   array('isbn' => '0435446576'),
   array('isbn' => '1741845467'),
   array('isbn' => '0750924721'),
   array('isbn' => '1843286432'),
   array('isbn' => '011331079X'),
   array('isbn' => '9063325819')
);
```

**normal array**

```
$arr2 = array(
   '1846031249',
   '0340912081',
   '0435446576',
   '1741845467',
   '0750924721',
   '1843286432',
   '011331079X',
   '9063325819'
);
```

Comment: Of course there's some difference. They do different things.

Comment: Are you trying to do 2D arrays? like a grid?

Comment: Don't thing anyone can measure it. However, why the first variant? Do you plan do introduce other values to the associative array later? If not, rename `$arr2` to `$isbns` and everything is fine.

Comment: the normal one directly accesses the value, the arrays of arrays goes thru a pointer to the array and then a hash look up on isbn and then you get the value ... the normal way is faster

Comment: @KingCrunch i have an array of arrays that i use for multiple functions and I don't think im bothered to create a new array if theres no performance difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do an array of arrays! You are needlessly increasing the amount of information you need to store in memory/process through. And in your case, when each value is simply an ISBN, keep track of the array so that you remember what's in it and scrap the repetitive labelling.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add complexity till you need it, and not before. There is nothing wrong with going back and editing your functions to use a new input format when things change. (I'm assuming this isn't a public API or something.)

Plus the array of arrays makes it very hard to sort, but worse it's impossible to check for the existence of an array value without iterating the entire array.

The regular array has lots of functions to make that work.

Answer (score 2):

It is useless to store every ISBN-code you have as an associative array with only one key. Think about it, which one would take longer? :

1. We're searching for ISBN = xxxxxxxxx. Open $array[0]->open $innerarray[0] -> not found -> close $innerarray -> open $array[1] -> open $innerarray[0] -> not found etc...
2. We're searching for ISBN = xxxxxxxxx. Open $array[0]-> not found -> open $array[1] -> not found -> open $array[2] etc...

The second method is much faster when you are storing 10.000 values in it. To open 10.000 arrays to search for values on $innerarray[0] takes more operations than to open only one array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first option takes a bit longer to initialize and takes more memory.

But one would not notice a difference unless he/she process them in loop thousand times or create very large array.

Comment: I will probably have roughtly around 10,000 values

Comment: Then it depends on. If you both (recieve data in that format e.g. from SQL query) and (pass to some function, which need array with `isbn` key), it may be ok. Otherwise don't use nested arrays.